# When did "comment" stop meaning "lie"?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology

A [*commentum*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dcommentum) (from [*comminiscor*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcomminiscor)) is, according to the *Elementary Latin Dictionary*:

> an invention, fabrication, pretence, fiction, falsehood

At some point, a *commentarium* (and, I presume, its cognate forms) came to mean something much more similar to English "commentary/comment," e.g. Aquinas's *In Aristotelis De Anima Commentarium*.

**How (and when) did *commentum* adopt this much more neutral meaning?**

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford English Dictionary entry for the English word *comment* says that Isidore's *Etymologies* (c. 600) uses *commentum* in the sense "a comment or interpretation".

I think it's necessary to distinguish between the word *commentum* and the word *commentarium*/*commentarius* when discussing the meaning and how it changed over time. I can't find any indication that *[commentarius](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcommentarius)* in Classical Latin had any implication of deliberate falsehood or fiction: it seems to have just referred to a notebook or notes, as in Caesar's *Commentarii de Bello Gallico.*

I would guess that the usage of *commentum* in later texts like Isidore's was influenced by the meaning of *commentarium* and the verb *[commento(r)](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcommentor1).*